# simplexml_load_file result issue

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am trying to read the output of an XML file that resides on a folder on my local box. In the PHP.net/simplexml_load_file tutorial the following LIKE code should show the SimpleXMLElement Object when I do a print_r($xml). But when I run the script on my local terminal I get the file path:

/Users/msavoy/XMLSourceDir/sfly-6x8.000020513524-7001536_28935-tb.33.xml

I need to be able to get the $xml object so that I can display all the elements within the object.

Here is my code:

```
// Get the correct count of the values in the $sourceXmlDir after the unset function completes
$sourceXmlArray = array_values($sourceXmlDir);
$count_xml_files = count($sourceXmlArray);

// Check to ensure that there are xml files in the directory before processing parsing the file
// If no files exist create an Exception and log the error.
if ($count_xml_files > 0) {

    // Cycle through the XML files in the $sourceXmlArray
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_xml_files; $i++) {

        $xml = ($sourceDir . '/' . $sourceXmlArray[$i]);

        print_r($xml);
    }
} else {
    $error_output = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . 'There are no XML files in the source directory: ' . $sourceDir;
    error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . 'There are no XML files in the source directory: ' . $sourceDir);
    throw new Exception($error_output);
}
```

What am I missing? Any help/direction would be appreciated. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = ($sourceDir . '/' . $sourceXmlArray[$i]);

print_r($xml);
```

You didn't actually call `simplexml_load_file`, so why would `$xml` be a `SimpleXMLElement` object?

Try this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($sourceDir . '/' . $sourceXmlArray[$i]);

print_r($xml);
```

Comment: Duh!! Sorry.  Obviously looking at this too long!!  Thank you.